# Install particular version with easy_install

Tags: python, version, easy-install

I'm trying to install `lxml`. I've had a look at the website, and version 2.2.8 looked reasonable to me but when I did `easy_install lxml`, it installed version 2.3.beta1 which is not really what I want I presume.

What is the best way to fix this and how can I force easy_install to install a particular version?

(Mac os x 10.6)

Comment: lxml depends on a few C libraries for xml, see the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504810/how-to-install-lxml-with-easy-install

Answer (score 142, accepted):

I believe the way to specify a version would be like this:

```
easy_install lxml==2.2.8
```

I (and most other Python users I suspect) stopped using `easy_install` and started using `pip` some time ago, so a solution in those terms is:

```
easy_install pip
pip install lxml==2.2.8
```

(`pip` has several benefits, including an `uninstall` command)

Answer (score 18):

From the easy_install [documentation](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#changing-the-active-version):

`easy_install PackageName==1.2.3`

Answer (score 7):

You should do something like this:

```
easy_install "lxml==2.2.8"
```