# How to install lxml on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, lxml, libxml2, easy-install

I'm having difficulty installing lxml with easy_install on Ubuntu 11.

When I type `$ easy_install lxml` I get:

```
Searching for lxml
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/
Reading http://codespeak.net/lxml
Best match: lxml 2.3
Downloading http://lxml.de/files/lxml-2.3.tgz
Processing lxml-2.3.tgz
Running lxml-2.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-7UdQOZ/lxml-2.3/egg-dist-tmp-GacQGy
Building lxml version 2.3.
Building without Cython.
ERROR: /bin/sh: xslt-config: not found

** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

Using build configuration of libxslt 
In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:227:0:
src/lxml/etree_defs.h:9:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

It seems that `libxslt` or `libxml2` is not installed. I've tried following the instructions at http://www.techsww.com/tutorials/libraries/libxslt/installation/installing_libxslt_on_ubuntu_linux.php and http://www.techsww.com/tutorials/libraries/libxml/installation/installing_libxml_on_ubuntu_linux.php with no success.

If I try `wget ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-sources-2.6.27.tar.gz` I get

```
<successful connection info>
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /libxml2 ... done.
==> SIZE libxml2-sources-2.6.27.tar.gz ... done.
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR libxml2-sources-2.6.27.tar.gz ... 
No such file `libxml2-sources-2.6.27.tar.gz'.
```

If I try the other first, I'll get to `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/libxslt --with-libxml-prefix=/usr/local/libxml2` and that will fail eventually with:

```
checking for libxml libraries >= 2.6.27... configure: error: Could not find libxml2 anywhere, check ftp://xmlsoft.org/.
```

I've tried both versions `2.6.27` and `2.6.29` of `libxml2` with no difference.

Leaving no stone unturned, I have successfully done `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`, but this changes nothing.

Answer (score 968, accepted):

Since you're on Ubuntu, don't bother with those source packages. Just install those development packages using apt-get.

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev
```

If you're happy with a possibly older version of lxml altogether though, you could try

```
apt-get install python-lxml
```

and be done with it. :)

Comment: this answer should be added to lxml install instructions :) thanks +1

Comment: This answer does not answer to question in the title 'with easy_install'

Comment: After running `apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev` you can just `easy_install lxml`

Comment: in the latest ubuntu-like distros, you have to install libxslt1-dev instead of libxslt-dev

Comment: Obviously not the (gr)easy_install way about it... however, it may help a fellow in a pinch to attempt `apt-get build-dep python-lxml` and then `STATIC_DEPS=true sudo pip install lxml`.

Comment: I have to install one additional package for my ubuntu 12.4 LTS: apt-get install libffi-dev

Comment: At least on Ubuntu 14.04 you also have to install the package `zlib1g-dev`.

Comment: @BobJansen python-dev is required, as the answer suggests - `easy_install lxml` won't work without it.  You possibly already had python-dev installed.

Comment: but what if I'm not root?

Comment: Similarly for python3.x. But when manually installing a new python you don't need the python3.x-dev.

Comment: what packages for Amazon EC2?

Comment: I had to install lib32z1-dev also in Ubuntu 14.04 to get it working actually.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 too `zlib1g-dev` is necessary. Without this I got the error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz`.

Comment: You also need pkg-config otherwise it'll fail to find xmlversion.h even if libxml2-dev is installed.

Comment: But why doesn't pip handle this - I thought pip handled installing requirements.  What is really going on? Or, what else might pip not work with?

Comment: There one sees how complex the world is.
And why does pip not handle it? - Because it's not 0install.
And why does it not work without being root? - Because too few care for 0install. We are not omniscient and not openminded enough - generic solution to package management seems to remove the reason for existence of distributions when they think their package manager is the one and only.
(There is the init system too. Nevertheless distros insist on theirs. My Tip Use both.)
So go ahead and use 0install and package programs/other projects only once. We also package electric and CAD projects.

Comment: the @Jabba comment should also be in the resolved answer.

Answer (score 114):

I also had to install lib32z1-dev before lxml would compile (Ubuntu 13.04 x64).

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1-dev
```

Or all the required packages together:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev lib32z1-dev
```

Comment: +1. This package was required even after installing all other mentioned packages.

Comment: yeh i also needed this on 13.04

Comment: Why does it need the *headers* of a lib32 package? Maybe zlib1g-dev would also work?

Comment: zlib1g-dev was needed on ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Also needed on 14.04 64 bit.

Answer (score 46):

As @Pepijn commented on @Druska 's answer, on ubuntu 13.04 x64, there is no need to use lib32z1-dev, zlib1g-dev is enough:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Answer (score 17):

I installed lxml with pip in Vagrant, using Ubuntu 14.04 and had the same problem. Even though all requirements where installed, i got the same error again and again. Turned out, my VM had to little memory by default. With 1024 MB everything works fine.

Add this to your VagrantFile and lxml should properly compile / install:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.memory = 1024
end
```

Thanks to sixhobbit for the hint (see: [can't installing lxml on Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894197/cant-installing-lxml-on-ubuntu-12-04)).

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. It said the compile failed with a status of 4, in case that helps anyone else.

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with OP's question

Answer (score 13):

**Step 1**

> Install latest python updates using this command.
>
> `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

**Step 2**

> Add first dependency ***libxml2*** version 2.7.0 or later
>
> `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`

**Step 3**

> Add second dependency ***libxslt*** version 1.1.23 or later
>
> `sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev`

**Step 4**

> Install ***pip*** package management tool first. and run this command.
>
> `pip install lxml`

If you have any doubt [Click Here](http://lxml.de/installation.html)

Comment: this was the only option that worked on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 10):

For Ubuntu 14.04

`sudo apt-get install python-lxml`

worked for me.

Comment: Well that's bad news. I've gained over 1000 rep from this question, if they have fixed that it will stop getting views ... 

Answer (score 8):

After installing the packages mentioned by AKX I still had the same problem. Solved it with

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

Answer (score 6):

For Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (Precise Pangolin) I had to do:

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

(Note the "1" in libxslt1-dev)

Then I just installed lxml with pip/easy_install.

Answer (score 3):

From Ubuntu 18.4 (Bionic Beaver) it is advisable to use apt instead of apt-get since it has much better structural form.

```
sudo apt install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev
```

If you're happy with a possibly older version of `lxml` altogether though, you could try

```
sudo apt install python-lxml
```

Answer (score 1):

First install Ubuntu's `python-lxml` package and its dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python-lxml
```

Then use `pip` to upgrade to the latest version of lxml for Python:

```
pip install lxml
```

Comment: code only answers are frowned upon. Add some explanation

Comment: While this answer may be correct, please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Comment: Downvoting because nothing new is added to a question that has several good answers already.

Answer (score 1):

Many answers here are rather old,
thanks to the pointer from @Simplans (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37759871/417747) and the [home page](https://lxml.de/installation.html)...

What worked for me (Ubuntu bionic):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-lxml
```

(+ `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev` I installed before it, but not sure if that's the requirement still)

Comment: Yeah, old answers on an old question. I mean, I was on Ubuntu 11 when I asked!

Comment: yes, I doubt you'd even be able to ask it here any more (would be moved over to ubuntu etc.) but it's still atrackting lot of web search. And doubt anyone is still using Ubuntu 11 :). And then that old linux versions and packages in-compatibility, hope that improves one day.

Answer (score 1):

**You can install lxml on Ubuntu by following these steps:**

- Open the terminal on your Ubuntu system.
- Update the package list by running the following command:

  ```
   sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Install the required dependencies by running the following command:

  ```
   sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
  ```
- Install lxml by running the following command:

  ```
   sudo pip install lxml
  ```
- If you don't have pip installed, you can install it by running the following command:

  ```
   sudo apt-get install python-pip
  ```
- Verify that lxml is installed by running the following command:

  ```
   python -c "import lxml; print(lxml.__version__)"
  ```

This should output the version number of lxml that you just installed.

**That's it!**