# Generating allure report using pytest

Tags: python, pytest, allure

I am using py test allure adaptor and trying to generate input data required for allure report. But I am not able to generate any XML's. When I execute the py file using py.test sample.py, it did create **pycache** dir. Then I executed "allure generate -v 1.3.9 C:\allurereports" (This is the dir where I had the sample.py). It did create an allure html report but no of test cases was 0. No details were present.

The sample.py(it is same as given in the example)

```
import allure


@allure.feature('Feature1')
@allure.story('Story1')
def test_minor():
    assert False


@allure.feature('Feature2')
@allure.story('Story2', 'Story3')
@allure.story('Story4')
class TestBar:

    # will have 'Feature2 and Story2 and Story3 and Story4'
    def test_bar(self):
        pass
```

Here's the py.test command used:
py.test sample.py --allure_features=feature1,feature2

Can anybody help me how to generate an allure report from the file? What are the commands to execute?

Answer (score 18):

Lavanya.
I'll try to explain the sequence you must to perform to generate allure report of autotest.

1. Install **pip**. Download  get-pip.py and perform **python get-pip.py**.
2. Install **pytest** and **pytest-allure-adaptor** via pip. Perform **python -m pip install pytest allure-pytest**
3. Generate autotest allure xml report. Perform **python -m pytest sample.py --alluredir <some directory>**
4. In <some directory> appear xml autotest report, which contain results of sample.py tests. Let's make beauty html report via an allure-cli tool.
5. Install allure-cli. Download [last version of allure-cli](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cli/releases/latest). allure-cli requires java. allure-cli doesn't require installation, [just unpack and use it](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cli#windows-and-other-unix).
6. Generate html report. Find allure (allure.bat for Windows) in unpacked zip. Perform **allure.bat generate -o <some directory> -v 1.4.0 <some directory>**
7. Find index.html in <some directory> and open it via a browser.

***Note** <some directory> the same for all steps

Comment: I've encounter some problems while installing package `pytest-allure-adaptor`. It depends on `lxml` and the last one is automatically installed first. See [Requires Distributions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-allure-adaptor) to get dependencies. Namely, `lxml` installation caused problems. Installation of packages `libxml2-dev` and `libxslt1-dev` into my system, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019942/why-cant-i-get-pip-install-lxml-to-work-within-a-virtualenv) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178416/pip-install-lxml-error), solved the problem.

Comment: pytest-allure-adaptor is deprecated and will not work on python 3.10, use allure-pytest instead.

Answer (score 5):

There is a very simple way to generate reports via allure:

first, install allure:

1. `allure-pytest 2.6.0`
2. `allure-python-commons 2.6.0`

Then, if you are unable to generate the reports, follow below steps:

1. (using pytest)

   ```
   pytest test_xyz.py --alluredir=path_where_you_want_to_save_reports
   ```
2. ```
   allure serve report_path
   ```

If it is still showing allure is not recognized command (blah -blah), then install allure using npm plugin with below command:

```
npm install -g allure-commandline --save-dev
```

then follow step (2) again, then one server will start and you will be able to see allure reports.

Comment: I am trying to generate report with allure-commons instead of Pytest. Can you please share the command for the same to create the XML & Json allure report files?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify **directory with your test data** (the directory which contains *-testsuite.xml* files), **not a test directory**.

You can use `py.test --alluredir [path_to_report_dir]` to specify it.

PS. Make sure you use right version of allure (latest pytest adapter supports only allure 1.4.*).

For more information see https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python and https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cli

Answer (score 1):

This is something that I found working -

```
python3 -m pytest [your_test_class_name] --alluredir \Report
```

Then perform the below line where you saved your report -

```
python3 -m allure serve \Report
```

This will open up the allure report in your default browser.

Answer (score 0):

now you must use allure-command-line instead of allure-cli to generate html-report, cause the second one is deprecated.