# Is it possible to execute a piece of commands written in text file using pycharm?

Tags: shell, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, pytest, allure

Is it possible to execute a piece of commands written in text file using pycharm?

Actually I am looking to execute a command "allure serve " (within from my selenium pytest framework) once after I close the browser OR once after I perform the 'yield'

Is there any way to write "allure serve " command inside my pytest framework or can I write this command in text file and can read the file once I perform yield?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can execute a system command with Python. Please have a look at the question [How to execute a program or call a system command from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command-from-python)
.

You could consider using an external package to integrate pytest with allure. Please check the question [Generating allure report using pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434791/generating-allure-report-using-pytest).