# Install lxml on OpenShift with python packages only (pip, easy_install)

Tags: pip, openshift, lxml, libxml2, easy-install

I am using Beautifulsoup with lxml package in my Django app (python 2.7). My production server is OpenShift, so I can not install using `apt-get` due to access rights. I was able to install lxml to OpenShift in past using `easy_install` in past, but I struggle to do so now.
Well probably I am missing some dependences that are installed through apt-get like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019942/why-cant-i-get-pip-install-lxml-to-work-within-a-virtualenv)?
I tried to install lxml by adding `lxml` to my setup.py file. Did not work.
So I tried `pip install lxml==3`:

```
> pip install lxml==3
Downloading/unpacking lxml==3
  Downloading lxml-3.0.tar.gz (3.2MB): 3.2MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package lxml
    Building lxml version 3.0.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'src/lxml/tests'
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    Building lxml version 3.0.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/var/lib/openshift/569eccb30c1e661fc20000d5/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/build/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_4XSLT_18__call__’:
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:132418: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy’ from incompatible pointer type
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:130379: note: expected ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *’ but argument is of type ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *’
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__copyXSLT’:
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133807: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy’ from incompatible pointer type
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:130379: note: expected ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *’ but argument is of type ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *’
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: At top level:
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:11938: warning: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_displayNode’ defined but not used
Connection to app-nick.rhcloud.com closed by remote host.
Connection to app-nick.rhcloud.com closed.
```

if I specify subversion (3.4 instead of 3) with pip there is a little bit different output:

```
pip install lxml==3.4
Downloading/unpacking lxml==3.4
  Downloading lxml-3.4.0.tar.gz (3.5MB): 3.5MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package lxml
    /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.4.0.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.4.0.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/var/lib/openshift/569eccb30c1e661fc20000d5/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/build/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
```

and easy_install:

```
> easy_install lxml
Searching for lxml
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/
Best match: lxml 3.5.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/l/lxml/lxml-3.5.0.tar.gz#md5=9f0c5f1eb43ff44d5455dab4b4efbe73
Processing lxml-3.5.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-K7xT2d/lxml-3.5.0/setup.cfg
Running lxml-3.5.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-K7xT2d/lxml-3.5.0/egg-dist-tmp-BAe44x
Building lxml version 3.5.0.
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
Connection to app-nick.rhcloud.com closed by remote host.
Connection to app-nick.rhcloud.com closed.
```

**How do I install lxml through pip or easy_install only?** Or should I use another xml parser with BeautifulSoup (not sure if there are alternatives)?

---

**UPDATE1**

I tried to install lxml==3.2.5. I forgot to mention I am on python 2.7 gear. If I add `, 'lxml==3.2.5'` to my `setup.py` file(I think setup.py works the same as `requirements.txt`), this is output:

```
remote: Searching for lxml==3.2.5
remote: Reading http://mirror1.ops.rhcloud.com/mirror/python/web/simple/lxml/
remote: Best match: lxml 3.2.5
remote: Downloading http://mirror1.ops.rhcloud.com/mirror/python/web/packages/source/l/lxml/lxml-3.2.5.tar.gz#md5=6c4fb9b1840631cff09b8229a12a9ef7
remote: Processing lxml-3.2.5.tar.gz
remote: Writing /tmp/easy_install-jvJHz8/lxml-3.2.5/setup.cfg
remote: Running lxml-3.2.5/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-jvJHz8/lxml-3.2.5/egg-dist-tmp-KMpa_f
remote: /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
remote:   warnings.warn(msg)
remote: warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'src/lxml/tests'
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_4data':
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97814: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxData' from incompatible pointer type
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97415: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_6start':
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97951: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxStart' from incompatible pointer type
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97115: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_8end':
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:98009: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxEnd' from incompatible pointer type
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97339: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_10pi':
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:98167: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxPi' from incompatible pointer type
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97455: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_12comment':
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:98220: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxComment' from incompatible pointer type
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97581: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__xslt_resolve_from_python':
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136117: warning: enumeration value '__pyx_e_4lxml_5etree_PARSER_DATA_INVALID' not handled in switch
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_4XSLT_18__call__':
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140191: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy' from incompatible pointer type
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:138126: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *'
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__copyXSLT':
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:141589: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy' from incompatible pointer type
remote: src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:138126: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *'
Connection to app-host.rhcloud.com closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: error in sideband demultiplexer
```

---

**UPDATE2**
I tried to install Cython (`pip install cython`), it also failed -> I was disconnected from OpenShift.
I have created bug report in [RedHat's bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1300356).

Comment: Did you try adding `lxml` in `requirements.txt` and pushing? That seems to install lxml 3.4.4 just fine for me with the Python 3.3 cartridge.

Comment: I install lxml setting the "requires" field in setup.py file "lxml==3.2.5" for my python 3.3 cartridge. There was a bug in Openshift a about a year or so ago that would only work with version 3.2.5. From what the previous poster states it looks like they might have fixed it.

Comment: hm, I am running on python 2.7. I will try to install your versions. Thanks

Comment: @fatfantasma I added output from trying to install lxml version 3.2.5.

Comment: Maybe it's a python 2.7 issue. I use lxml and beautifulsoup in all of my Openshift apps with python 3.3

Comment: Yep, but that is weird. I do run lxml on my other python 2.7 app. But I wanted to move that app to scalable, so I needed to create new. And I can find out how I was able to install lxml before.

Comment: Does it work for you with a python3.3 app from scratch? I [can't install lxml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529761/openshift-cant-install-lxml-for-python-app). I see that you created a bug report on RedHat's bugzilla. I will ask there too to get someone from openshift in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird bug, Maciej from RedHat suggested I **recreate Openshift app** again from scratch. It worked and I was able to install lxml successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For the **UPDATE1** symptoms, except not giving the version number in the `requirements.txt` as it was a dependency for another library I was using, this fixed it for me:

1. `rhc ssh` to the application
2. run `pip install lxml`
3. run `pip install lxml` again

After Step 2. (the first `pip` run) the output was:

```
Downloading/unpacking lxml

pip can't proceed with requirement 'lxml' due to a pre-existing build directory.
 location: /var/lib/openshift/xxx/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/build/lxml
This is likely due to a previous installation that failed.
pip is being responsible and not assuming it can delete this.
Please delete it and try again.

Cleaning up...
```

The second `pip` run finished successfully and there was no need to delete the directory `pip` suggested (nor did it exist).

`pip` was using `lxml` version 3.6.0 - python 2.7 as cartridge.