# openshift: can't install lxml for python app

Tags: python, git, openshift, lxml

I am trying Openshift but I can't deploy a python app with `lxml`.

Below are my steps, I'm only adding a `lxml` requirement. The error happens when I push.

I am able to ssh so I don't think it's a problem of connectivity.

If I don't add the lxml requirement but add some other libraries, it works.

The problem is with lxml only. I think it's because it has some system dependencies (I have to run this on a ubuntu machine before: `sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev`)

However I don't think I can do this for an openshift app. Is there no way to install lxml then?

---

Commands

```
rhc app create testlxml python-3.3
echo 'lxml' > testlxml/requirements.txt
cd testlxml
git add .
git commit -m "Add lxml requirement"
git push
```

Result:

```
vagrant@dev:~$ rhc app create testlxml python-3.3
RSA 1024 bit CA certificates are loaded due to old openssl compatibility
Application Options
-------------------
Domain:     mikep
Cartridges: python-3.3
Gear Size:  default
Scaling:    no

Creating application 'testlxml' ... done


Waiting for your DNS name to be available ... done

Cloning into 'testlxml'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '54.84.57.164' to the list of known hosts.

Your application 'testlxml' is now available.

  URL:        http://testlxml-mikep.rhcloud.com/
  SSH to:     56c8e1a789f5cf57a3000116@testlxml-mikep.rhcloud.com
  Git remote: ssh://56c8e1a789f5cf57a3000116@testlxml-mikep.rhcloud.com/~/git/testlxml.git/
  Cloned to:  /home/vagrant/testlxml

Run 'rhc show-app testlxml' for more details about your app.

vagrant@dev:~$ echo 'lxml' > testlxml/requirements.txt
vagrant@dev:~$ cd testlxml
vagrant@dev:~/testlxml$ git add .
vagrant@dev:~/testlxml$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   requirements.txt

vagrant@dev:~/testlxml$ git commit -m "Add lxml requirement"
[master c1776a9] Add lxml requirement
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

vagrant@dev:~/testlxml$ git push
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

In Git 2.0, Git will default to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 270 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Stopping Python 3.3 cartridge
remote: Waiting for stop to finish
remote: Waiting for stop to finish
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit c1776a9
remote: Activating virtenv
remote: Checking for pip dependency listed in requirements.txt file..
remote: The directory '/var/lib/openshift/56c8e1a789f5cf57a3000116/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
remote: The directory '/var/lib/openshift/56c8e1a789f5cf57a3000116/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
remote: Collecting lxml (from -r /var/lib/openshift/56c8e1a789f5cf57a3000116/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:   Downloading http://mirror1.ops.rhcloud.com/mirror/python/web/packages/source/l/lxml/lxml-3.5.0.tar.gz (3.8MB)
remote: Installing collected packages: lxml
remote:   Running setup.py install for lxml: started
Connection to testlxml-mikep.rhcloud.com closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: error in sideband demultiplexer
To ssh://56c8e1a789f5cf57a3000116@testlxml-mikep.rhcloud.com/~/git/testlxml.git/
   cfd1b36..c1776a9  master -> master
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://56c8e1a789f5cf57a3000116@testlxml-mikep.rhcloud.com/~/git/testlxml.git/'
```

Comment: How much time did it take from `push` command to error? Are the permissions right for your repo on `testlxml-mikep.rhcloud.com`?

Comment: I just tried with some other libraries and it works. So the problem is with lxml. I think it's because it has some system dependencies (I have to run this on a ubuntu machine before: `sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev`) However I don't think I can do this for an openshift app. Is there no way to install lxml then?

Answer (score 2):

Openshift is only able to compile/install 'lxml==3.2.5' the last time I checked.

Set your 'requires' in your setup.py to  'lxml==3.2.5'.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I didn't think of trying an older version. It seems to work up to `lxml==3.4.4`

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

The latest version of `lxml` (`3.5.0`) does not work but `lxml==3.4.4` works.