# Error installing libxml2-dev on Ubuntu 9.10 - for lxml-etree

Tags: python, installation, lxml, ubuntu-9.10, xml.etree

Trying to install **lxml-etree** on **Ubuntu 9.10**
[I learned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504810/how-to-install-lxml-on-ubuntu) that I need to have **libxml2-dev** & **libxslt-dev**

When I try to install libxml2-dev, by running `apt-get install libxml2-dev`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libxml2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libxml2-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libxml2
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 73 not upgraded.
Need to get 1696kB of archives.
After this operation, 2830kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main libxml2 2.7.5.dfsg-1ubuntu1.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/main libxml2 2.7.5.dfsg-1ubuntu1.2
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/main libxml2-dev 2.7.5.dfsg-1ubuntu1.2
  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2_2.7.5.dfsg-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2-dev_2.7.5.dfsg-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Is this version of lxml removed ?
**Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2_2.7.5.dfsg-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found**

Hence I tried to run `apt-get install python-lxml` the way it was suggested in that thread.
But that gives me this :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  python-lxml-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-lxml
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 74 not upgraded.
Need to get 1265kB of archives.
After this operation, 4002kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main python-lxml 2.1.5-1ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lxml/python-lxml_2.1.5-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: And have you run the `apr-get update` and then tried again?

Comment: just "apt-get update" ? or something after that ? e.g. "apt-get update python-lxml"

Comment: Try doing `apt-get update` (to bring your local repo up to date -- never hurts anyway), then `apt-get install python-lxml` to see what happens

Comment: did an "apt-get update", but that gave me a number of errors, on this line --> W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

Comment: Umm, is `lxml` not installed by default on 9.10 ? (ie. just check by loading Python and `import lxml`)

Comment: Maybe ask on askubuntu.com as I think it comes down more to package management that's system related than programming and Python related (short of someone having the time to walk you through downloading and compiling sources)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21653/discussion-between-planetunknown-and-jon-clements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 9.10 isn't supported anymore hence couldn't get this working.
Created a new 12.04 host.