# Django-Haystack and Solr can not rebuild index

Tags: solr, django-haystack

Trying to rebuild index after switching from whoosh to Solr with no luck.

These are search_indexes.py

```
"""Haystack search index for jobs app"""

from haystack.indexes import *  #@UnusedWildImport
from haystack import site

from cthr.jobs.models import Submission


class SubmissionIndex(SearchIndex):
    """SearchIndex for job submission searching"""
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    active = BooleanField(model_attr='active')
    submit_date = DateTimeField(model_attr='created')

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return Submission.objects.all()

    def get_updated_field(self):
        """Specify which field is used to calculate the age of a Submission for re-indexing"""
        return 'modified'


# Wire 'em up
site.register(Submission, SubmissionIndex)
```

2nd one is this.

```
"""Haystack search index for resumes app"""

from haystack.indexes import *  #@UnusedWildImport
from haystack import site

from cthr.resumes.models import Resume


class StructuredResumeIndex(SearchIndex):
    """SearchIndex for Structured Resume searching"""
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    employee = BooleanField(model_attr='employee')
    available = BooleanField(model_attr='available')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Resume.objects.all()

    def get_updated_field(self):
        """Specify which field is used to calculate the age of a Submission for re-indexing"""
        return 'modified'

# Wire 'em up
site.register(Resume, StructuredResumeIndex)
```

This is the error I get when running rebuild_index:

```
Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
DEBUG pysolr Starting request to 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/update/?commit=true' (post) with body 'u'<delete>'...
INFO requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1
DEBUG requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /solr/update/?commit=true HTTP/1.1" 200 None
INFO pysolr Finished 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/update/?commit=true' (post) with body 'u'<delete>' in 0.357 seconds.
DEBUG pysolr Starting request to 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/update/?commit=true' (post) with body 'u'<optimiz'...
INFO requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1
DEBUG requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool "POST /solr/update/?commit=true HTTP/1.1" 200 None
INFO pysolr Finished 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/update/?commit=true' (post) with body 'u'<optimiz' in 0.049 seconds.
All documents removed.
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py:84: UserWarning: 'SearchIndex.get_queryset' is pending deprecation & will be removed in Haystack v2. Please rename them to 'index_queryset'.
  warnings.warn("'SearchIndex.get_queryset' is pending deprecation & will be removed in Haystack v2. Please rename them to 'index_queryset'.")
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.002) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "jobs_submission"; args=()
Indexing 0 submissions.
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "jobs_submission"."id" FROM "jobs_submission" ORDER BY "jobs_submission"."id" ASC; args=()
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "resumes_resume"; args=()
Indexing 3 resumes.
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_resume"."id" FROM "resumes_resume" ORDER BY "resumes_resume"."id" ASC; args=()
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_resume"."id", "resumes_resume"."created", "resumes_resume"."modified", "resumes_resume"."user_id", "resumes_resume"."name", "resumes_resume"."slug", "resumes_resume"."blinded_name", "resumes_resume"."blinded_slug", "resumes_resume"."overview", "resumes_resume"."objective", "resumes_resume"."title", "resumes_resume"."employee", "resumes_resume"."available", "resumes_resume"."location", "resumes_resume"."relocation_options", "resumes_resume"."clearance", "resumes_resume"."skills_text", "resumes_resume"."email", "resumes_resume"."phone_home", "resumes_resume"."phone_mobile", "resumes_resume"."phone_work", "resumes_resume"."file" FROM "resumes_resume" ORDER BY "resumes_resume"."id" ASC LIMIT 3; args=()
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_skill"."id", "resumes_skill"."skill" FROM "resumes_skill" INNER JOIN "resumes_resume_skills" ON ("resumes_skill"."id" = "resumes_resume_skills"."skill_id") WHERE "resumes_resume_skills"."resume_id" = 1  ORDER BY "resumes_skill"."skill" ASC; args=(1,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_skill"."id", "resumes_skill"."skill" FROM "resumes_skill" INNER JOIN "resumes_resume_skills" ON ("resumes_skill"."id" = "resumes_resume_skills"."skill_id") WHERE "resumes_resume_skills"."resume_id" = 1  ORDER BY "resumes_skill"."skill" ASC; args=(1,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_affiliation"."id", "resumes_affiliation"."resume_id", "resumes_affiliation"."affiliation" FROM "resumes_affiliation" WHERE "resumes_affiliation"."resume_id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_affiliation"."id", "resumes_affiliation"."resume_id", "resumes_affiliation"."affiliation" FROM "resumes_affiliation" WHERE "resumes_affiliation"."resume_id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_certification"."id", "resumes_certification"."resume_id", "resumes_certification"."certification" FROM "resumes_certification" WHERE "resumes_certification"."resume_id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_certification"."id", "resumes_certification"."resume_id", "resumes_certification"."certification" FROM "resumes_certification" WHERE "resumes_certification"."resume_id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_education"."id", "resumes_education"."resume_id", "resumes_education"."level", "resumes_education"."honors", "resumes_education"."discipline", "resumes_education"."minor", "resumes_education"."school", "resumes_education"."location", "resumes_education"."year" FROM "resumes_education" WHERE "resumes_education"."resume_id" = 1  ORDER BY "resumes_education"."year" DESC; args=(1,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_education"."id", "resumes_education"."resume_id", "resumes_education"."level", "resumes_education"."honors", "resumes_education"."discipline", "resumes_education"."minor", "resumes_education"."school", "resumes_education"."location", "resumes_education"."year" FROM "resumes_education" WHERE "resumes_education"."resume_id" = 1  ORDER BY "resumes_education"."year" DESC; args=(1,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_publication"."id", "resumes_publication"."resume_id", "resumes_publication"."publication" FROM "resumes_publication" WHERE "resumes_publication"."resume_id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_publication"."id", "resumes_publication"."resume_id", "resumes_publication"."publication" FROM "resumes_publication" WHERE "resumes_publication"."resume_id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_jobhistory"."id", "resumes_jobhistory"."resume_id", "resumes_jobhistory"."title", "resumes_jobhistory"."company", "resumes_jobhistory"."location", "resumes_jobhistory"."date_from", "resumes_jobhistory"."date_to", "resumes_jobhistory"."description", "resumes_jobhistory"."skills_text" FROM "resumes_jobhistory" WHERE "resumes_jobhistory"."resume_id" = 1  ORDER BY "resumes_jobhistory"."date_from" DESC; args=(1,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_jobhistory"."id", "resumes_jobhistory"."resume_id", "resumes_jobhistory"."title", "resumes_jobhistory"."company", "resumes_jobhistory"."location", "resumes_jobhistory"."date_from", "resumes_jobhistory"."date_to", "resumes_jobhistory"."description", "resumes_jobhistory"."skills_text" FROM "resumes_jobhistory" WHERE ("resumes_jobhistory"."resume_id" = 1  AND "resumes_jobhistory"."date_to" IS NULL) ORDER BY "resumes_jobhistory"."date_from" DESC; args=(1,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_jobhistory"."id", "resumes_jobhistory"."resume_id", "resumes_jobhistory"."title", "resumes_jobhistory"."company", "resumes_jobhistory"."location", "resumes_jobhistory"."date_from", "resumes_jobhistory"."date_to", "resumes_jobhistory"."description", "resumes_jobhistory"."skills_text" FROM "resumes_jobhistory" WHERE ("resumes_jobhistory"."resume_id" = 1  AND "resumes_jobhistory"."date_to" IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY "resumes_jobhistory"."date_to" DESC; args=(1,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_skill"."id", "resumes_skill"."skill" FROM "resumes_skill" INNER JOIN "resumes_jobhistory_skills" ON ("resumes_skill"."id" = "resumes_jobhistory_skills"."skill_id") WHERE "resumes_jobhistory_skills"."jobhistory_id" = 1  ORDER BY "resumes_skill"."skill" ASC; args=(1,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_skill"."id", "resumes_skill"."skill" FROM "resumes_skill" INNER JOIN "resumes_jobhistory_skills" ON ("resumes_skill"."id" = "resumes_jobhistory_skills"."skill_id") WHERE "resumes_jobhistory_skills"."jobhistory_id" = 1  ORDER BY "resumes_skill"."skill" ASC; args=(1,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_skill"."id", "resumes_skill"."skill" FROM "resumes_skill" INNER JOIN "resumes_resume_skills" ON ("resumes_skill"."id" = "resumes_resume_skills"."skill_id") WHERE "resumes_resume_skills"."resume_id" = 2  ORDER BY "resumes_skill"."skill" ASC; args=(2,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_skill"."id", "resumes_skill"."skill" FROM "resumes_skill" INNER JOIN "resumes_resume_skills" ON ("resumes_skill"."id" = "resumes_resume_skills"."skill_id") WHERE "resumes_resume_skills"."resume_id" = 2  ORDER BY "resumes_skill"."skill" ASC; args=(2,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_affiliation"."id", "resumes_affiliation"."resume_id", "resumes_affiliation"."affiliation" FROM "resumes_affiliation" WHERE "resumes_affiliation"."resume_id" = 2 ; args=(2,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_certification"."id", "resumes_certification"."resume_id", "resumes_certification"."certification" FROM "resumes_certification" WHERE "resumes_certification"."resume_id" = 2 ; args=(2,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_education"."id", "resumes_education"."resume_id", "resumes_education"."level", "resumes_education"."honors", "resumes_education"."discipline", "resumes_education"."minor", "resumes_education"."school", "resumes_education"."location", "resumes_education"."year" FROM "resumes_education" WHERE "resumes_education"."resume_id" = 2  ORDER BY "resumes_education"."year" DESC; args=(2,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_publication"."id", "resumes_publication"."resume_id", "resumes_publication"."publication" FROM "resumes_publication" WHERE "resumes_publication"."resume_id" = 2 ; args=(2,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_jobhistory"."id", "resumes_jobhistory"."resume_id", "resumes_jobhistory"."title", "resumes_jobhistory"."company", "resumes_jobhistory"."location", "resumes_jobhistory"."date_from", "resumes_jobhistory"."date_to", "resumes_jobhistory"."description", "resumes_jobhistory"."skills_text" FROM "resumes_jobhistory" WHERE "resumes_jobhistory"."resume_id" = 2  ORDER BY "resumes_jobhistory"."date_from" DESC; args=(2,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_skill"."id", "resumes_skill"."skill" FROM "resumes_skill" INNER JOIN "resumes_resume_skills" ON ("resumes_skill"."id" = "resumes_resume_skills"."skill_id") WHERE "resumes_resume_skills"."resume_id" = 3  ORDER BY "resumes_skill"."skill" ASC; args=(3,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_affiliation"."id", "resumes_affiliation"."resume_id", "resumes_affiliation"."affiliation" FROM "resumes_affiliation" WHERE "resumes_affiliation"."resume_id" = 3 ; args=(3,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_certification"."id", "resumes_certification"."resume_id", "resumes_certification"."certification" FROM "resumes_certification" WHERE "resumes_certification"."resume_id" = 3 ; args=(3,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_education"."id", "resumes_education"."resume_id", "resumes_education"."level", "resumes_education"."honors", "resumes_education"."discipline", "resumes_education"."minor", "resumes_education"."school", "resumes_education"."location", "resumes_education"."year" FROM "resumes_education" WHERE "resumes_education"."resume_id" = 3  ORDER BY "resumes_education"."year" DESC; args=(3,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_publication"."id", "resumes_publication"."resume_id", "resumes_publication"."publication" FROM "resumes_publication" WHERE "resumes_publication"."resume_id" = 3 ; args=(3,)
DEBUG django.db.backends (0.000) SELECT "resumes_jobhistory"."id", "resumes_jobhistory"."resume_id", "resumes_jobhistory"."title", "resumes_jobhistory"."company", "resumes_jobhistory"."location", "resumes_jobhistory"."date_from", "resumes_jobhistory"."date_to", "resumes_jobhistory"."description", "resumes_jobhistory"."skills_text" FROM "resumes_jobhistory" WHERE "resumes_jobhistory"."resume_id" = 3  ORDER BY "resumes_jobhistory"."date_from" DESC; args=(3,)
DEBUG pysolr Starting to build add request...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/management/commands/rebuild_index.py", line 16, in handle
    call_command('update_index', **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 150, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 193, in handle
    return super(Command, self).handle(*apps, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 304, in handle
    app_output = self.handle_app(app, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 229, in handle_app
    do_update(index, qs, start, end, total, self.verbosity)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 109, in do_update
    index.backend.update(index, current_qs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py", line 73, in update
    self.conn.add(docs, commit=commit, boost=index.get_field_weights())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysolr.py", line 740, in add
    message.append(self._build_doc(doc, boost=boost))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysolr.py", line 695, in _build_doc
    field = ET.Element('field', **attrs)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2560, in lxml.etree.Element (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:52924)
TypeError: Element() keywords must be strings
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, from what I have seen and googled it is telling me that I am passing unicode while it expects a string?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue and I got it fixed.

look at the answer to this question:

[How to install lxml on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504810/how-to-install-lxml-on-ubuntu)

how did you install `lxml`? What i did is I went to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and deleted the `lxml` directories and ran the command from the above link:

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

The problem then went away.

Comment: For those of you that might struggle also get python-dev! Thank you, your dependencies did the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it upgrading the `lxml` version with:

```
pip install --upgrade lxml
```

More information [here](https://github.com/toastdriven/pysolr/issues/72)