# can't installing lxml on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, lxml, python-import

I've been trying to install lxml using `pip install lxml` and I get the error below.  I've used `apt-get install python-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev` before (suggested in other answers) but I still get the same error.  I did not use control-c.

```
pip install lxml
Downloading/unpacking lxml
  Downloading lxml-3.2.4.tar.gz (3.3MB): 3.3MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package lxml
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.2.4.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'src/lxml/tests'
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.2.4.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/home/mlkang/Envs/env1/build/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_4data':
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97799:74: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxData' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97400:12: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_6start':
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97936:75: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxStart' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97100:18: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_8end':
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97994:73: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxEnd' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97324:18: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_10pi':
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:98152:72: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxPi' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97440:18: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_12comment':
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:98205:77: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxComment' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97566:18: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__xslt_resolve_from_python':
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136086:9: warning: enumeration value '__pyx_e_4lxml_5etree_PARSER_DATA_INVALID' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_4XSLT_18__call__':
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140160:81: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:138095:52: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *'
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__copyXSLT':
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:141558:79: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:138095:52: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *'
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: At top level:
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:12770:13: warning: '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_displayNode' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4
Complete output from command /home/mlkang/Envs/env1/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/mlkang/Envs/env1/build/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-zVBvtO-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/mlkang/Envs/env1/include/site/python2.7:
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

  warnings.warn(msg)

Building lxml version 3.2.4.

Building without Cython.

Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26

Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

running build_ext

building 'lxml.etree' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/home/mlkang/Envs/env1/build/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_4data':

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97799:74: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxData' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97400:12: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_6start':

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97936:75: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxStart' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97100:18: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_8end':

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97994:73: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxEnd' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97324:18: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_10pi':

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:98152:72: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxPi' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97440:18: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder_12comment':

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:98205:77: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11TreeBuilder__handleSaxComment' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97566:18: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_TreeBuilder *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__SaxParserTarget *'

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__xslt_resolve_from_python':

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136086:9: warning: enumeration value '__pyx_e_4lxml_5etree_PARSER_DATA_INVALID' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_4XSLT_18__call__':

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140160:81: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:138095:52: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *'

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__copyXSLT':

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:141558:79: warning: passing argument 1 of '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:138095:52: note: expected 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *' but argument is of type 'struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *'

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: At top level:

src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:12770:13: warning: '__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_displayNode' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]

gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)

Please submit a full bug report,

with preprocessed source if appropriate.

See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4

----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Doesn't this belong to http://unix.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Did you kill the compiler with Control-C or does it really crash?

Comment: @l19 Sorry, did I put this is the wrong site?

Comment: @Christian Rapp I did not use control-C

Comment: I get the same or similar warning messages. Try downloading the sources and compile yourself with make. This worked for me, but I did not try with pip!

Comment: Ever have luck with this? Running into the same thing. I've installed all the dependencies I've seen recommended.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this to get the deps:

```
apt-get build-dep python-lxml
```

Comment: I feel like i have installed over 500 Mb of lxml dependencies int he last 30 minutes :/ Thanks for the final clue I needed :)

Comment: Same as person above! I've installed tons of libraries, only to find that yours was the last one I needed! Thank you!!!!

Comment: This worked for me. I am using python 3 so my command was `sudo apt-get build-dep python3-lxml`

Answer (score 11):

I had exactly this problem. Turned out to be a memory problem - I was installing reporter.py, which depends on lxml, on a server with only 500MB RAM, of which only 150MB was free. I killed off a few things to get up to ~300MB free, and just managed to squeeze out the installation of  lxml. (Watching TOP showed available memory going down to 4MB at one point!)

see http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48796

Comment: I had the same problem and my solution was based on yours. Actually, I'm using Vagrant and my VM was with only 512 MB RAM, so I've changed this limit to 1 GB. The installation ocurred without error.

Comment: I have solved this by adding swap file with 500M size because there was no ability to increase RAM.

Comment: Same for me.  Vagrant default box.  Bumped up to 1024 with 
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = 1024
  end
fixes this hellish error.