# Looking for a pcap module on python 3.4

Tags: python, pcap

I am looking for a pcap module or wrapper which works on python 3.4 and linux.
It would be nice if it would work with win32 too.

For any suggestion I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

`Pyshark` (http://kiminewt.github.io/pyshark/) works with python 3.4. It is installed with

`pip3 install pyshark`

It depends on `lxml` which may be not straightforward to install (see this question [can't installing lxml on Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894197/cant-installing-lxml-on-ubuntu-12-04)).