# The command '/bin/sh -c sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am running into issues building my Docker container. Not entirely sure what I need to do here.

### Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y tar git curl nano wget dialog net-tools build-essential \
&& apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q python3 python3-pip python3-dev
ADD . /bot
WORKDIR /bot
RUN sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

### Requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
Werkzeug==0.11.3
itsdangerous==0.24
lxml==3.5.0
requests==2.9.1
uWSGI==2.0.12
wikiquote==0.1.2
```

### errors

http://hastebin.com/ipatorezos.coffee

### [Edit] This appears to fix it. Added other input. Thanks!

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y tar git curl nano wget dialog net-tools build-essential \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q python3 python3-pip python3-dev \
    && apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev zlib1g-dev
ADD . /bot
WORKDIR /bot
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

Comment: Is libxml2 installed?

Comment: You don't need `sudo` in a docker file as all commands run as root.

Comment: There is no error to know what the issue symptoms look like. That pastebin link does not work.

Comment: This is a 2 year old question that has already been resolved.

Comment: But to understand if the question is similar to your own problem, it is necessary to see the error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be around:

```
Using build configuration of libxslt
        building 'lxml.etree' extension
        x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
        In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:323:0:
        src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:14:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
         #include "libxml/xmlversion.h"
```

From "[How to install lxml on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19289133/6309)", add to your Dockerfile:

```
&& apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Also, [make sure your VM has enough memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25372234/6309) (if the [`apt-get install` fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22256546/6309)).

The OP confirms the full apt-get command would be:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y tar git curl nano wget dialog net-tools build-essential \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q python3 python3-pip python3-dev \
    && apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev zlib1g-dev
```