# pip install lxml failiing

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pip

I am on an ubuntu 14.04 machine and I am getting failures while deploying a django app of mine in a python 2.7 venv. My local machine is osx and it gave me no problems when installing this.

```
pip install lxml
```

and it outputs this error http://pastebin.com/NZskmJsm

I have followed everything I have found so far on SO and it has not been a help [pip install lxml error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178416/pip-install-lxml-error)

IDK where to go from here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install lxml on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504810/how-to-install-lxml-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I have followed everything on there, and it didn't work, but I did find that it works on my system-wide python, just not the virtual environment. How can I go about getting it to work in the venv?

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455238/lxml-installation-error-ubuntu-14-04-internal-compiler-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894197/cant-installing-lxml-on-ubuntu-12-04?

Comment: May be this works for you pip install -U pip setuptools and then apt-get update and then apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev and then  do pip install lxml.

Comment: It was a memory issue, I have to add a swapfile because it is a small VPS