# Pip install error missing 'libxml/xmlversion.h'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-module, python-packaging

I need to install the python package xmlsec(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmlsec) and when I try running

```
pip install xmlsec
```

It gives me this error:

```
src\xmlsec\constants.c(266) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
```

When I first researched this error I found numerous answers that it had to do with the installed lxml package. After trying:

```
pip install --upgrade lxml
```

It wasn't able to upgrade and so I uninstalled lxml and installed it again but there was an IO error. In the end I downloaded the lxml file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml and placed it in my python directory and installed it as the answer from this question did: [Installing lxml, libxml2, libxslt on Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493031/solved-installing-lxml-libxml2-libxslt-on-windows-8-1)

It uploaded successfully and when running pip upgrade, it says it is up to date.

**The same error though still persists from trying to install xmlsec though with 'libxml/xmlversion.h' missing. Does anyone know what else can be the problem here?**

Note: I'm using python 2.7 on windows

Comment: can you search for the file `xmlversion.h` on your machine? On my Ubuntu it is at `/usr/include/libxml2/libxml`, but I'm guessing you are using Windows 8.1

Comment: Installing a python distribution instead of the python interpreter alone is a good idea if you are on Windows. [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), for example, should take care of installing all lxml dependencies so you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 41):

You may need to install the header files for `libxml` and `libxml-sec`. You do not indicate which platform you are running on. If you run on ubuntu you need to `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev`.

Comment: I'm on windows, do you know how I would go about this?

Comment: I don't know much about windows. Perhaps have a look here https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/faq.html

Comment: On Alpine, you can do:
`apk add libxml2-dev libxslt-dev`