# error installing python-pptx on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-pptx

I use python 2.7.12 with updated pip

I need to install python-pptx on windows 7 64 bit machine,

I try to use pip install python-pptx and get

Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='c:\users\thebea~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-dmvmgk\lxml\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\thebea~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-py7w8l-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\thebea~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-dmvmgk\lxml\

when i try to use easy install 
easy_install python-pptx 
I get 
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\Users\thebeancounter\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

When i try scipy it's similar and when i install other packages it's ok, python is running and defined in the path

I found [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) and installed python c++ compiler for windows

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413824/installing-numpy-on-windows) and installed the sdk

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: Does `import lxml` work in Python on that machine? If not I'd start with installing that from a binary distribution (32-bit IINM, even though OS is 64-bit).

Comment: The import does not work, pip install lxml also does not work, 
is there any straightforward to do so with python pptx directly?

Comment: See if [the answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493031/installing-lxml-libxml2-libxslt-on-windows-8-1) get you any further along. In any case, it's a frequent question, if you search on 'install lxml windows 7 64' you should find lots of resources. Note that you may need the 32-bit lxml because the default Python install for Windows may be 32-bit.

Comment: please post this as answer for me to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the `lxml` install, which `python-pptx` depends on. Because `lxml` depends on compiled C code, it requires a compiler in order to install it from the source package.

The solution is to install a pre-compiled `lxml` package, in the form of a "wheel" (.whl file). You can get those here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml. Pick the one with the "cp*" number matching your Python version, e.g. 'cp27' for Python 2.7.  Note that you may need the 32-bit lxml because the default Python install for Windows may be 32-bit.

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493031/installing-lxml-libxml2-libxslt-on-windows-8-1) may have additional details and if you search on 'install lxml windows 7 64' you'll find additional resources.