# Problems with packages installing plone on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, plone

I am trying to install plone on ubuntu

I have downloaded and extracted the installer file.
When I type: `./install.sh standalone` I get the following message:

```
Plone installation requires the development versions of libxml2 and libxslt.
libxml2 must be version 2.7.8 or greater; libxslt must be 1.1.26 or greater.
Ideally, you should install these as dev package libraries before running install.sh.
```

I then tried to run: `sudo apt-get install libxslt` (and same for libxml2 whic worked). 
I am getting the message: `E: Unable to locate package libxslt`

Is there another package I must install that supports the libxslt, or how can I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Ubuntu system, there is a package named `libxslt1.1`. You can try installing that one. If that doesn't work, try one of the dev packages, `libxslt-dev` or `libxslt1-dev`.

Comment: Correct answer, still worthwile pointing out, that the dev-versions are the recommended ones, see:
http://docs.plone.org/manage/installing/installation.html#install-the-operating-system-software-and-libraries-needed-to-run-plone

Comment: Not just recommended; required. Without the development headers we can't build the required Python packages.

Comment: @SteveM: Oh yes, it was the wrong word, thanks for correcting!

Answer (score 5):

I think in any case you would need `libxml2-devel` and `libxslt-devel` (or `-dev`? It's possible that different distributions have different conventions for this.) [This related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6504860/505649) suggests the package name might be `libxslt1-dev`.

If all else fails, but this is somewhat frowned upon, the installer has a last resort option:

> --static-lxml
>   Forces a static built of libxml2 and libxslt dependencies. 
>   Requires Internet access to download components.

(But this cuts you off from all future security updates etc. in libxml and lixslt2.)

Comment: Plus one for pointing out the alternative. When the xslt-libs became required (because of plone.app.theming a.k.a. "Diazo"), I was very thankful for the static libs. It is actually a nice approach of becoming agnostic towards the system's setup, but would require extra-efforts, to update the static-libs regularly. Just, if you know by any chance: I wonder, if these libs are neccessary for other packages too, or if they can be safely omitted, if one doesn't install Diazo?

Comment: BTW, the required libs and their names for different operating-system's are very well documented (praise the doc-team, everyone):
http://docs.plone.org/manage/installing/installation.html#install-the-operating-system-software-and-libraries-needed-to-run-plone

Comment: @IdaEbkes: I think they've been a dependency at least back to Plone 4.0.x, long before diazo. Maybe from the outputfilters?

Comment: Ah, yes, that could be likely a case. So, probably just the requirement to use the newest xslt-libs-versions, where what changed. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ubuntu/Debian you can run the following command to install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.