# Get selected value of dropdown with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to get the selected value of a dropdown box with next code:

```
scenario 'USA as default country' do
  expect(page).to have_select('report_country_code', selected: 'United States')
end
```

Html for this field is the next:

```
<select class="form-control country required" name="report[country_code]" id="report_country_code">
  <option value="US">United States</option>
  ....
  ....
  <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

And the error looks like:

```
expected to find select box "report_country_code" with "United States" selected but there were no matches. Also found "United States .... Zimbabwe", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

Comment: `have_select(..., selected: '...')` is correct, but the error is saying that your page has the `select` tag but `"United States"` is not selected. And indeed in your sample HTML the "United States" option does not have the `selected` property, which would explain the error.

Comment: @shioyama, thanks, that clear now. But why I can test this form and do not to select Country (this field is neccessary)? And when I visit /new form in browser, I see "United States" in this field..

Comment: I suppose it appears selected because it is the first in the list of options.

Comment: Since you have a 'required' class on the element and not the required attribute, I assume you're using a JS library to do the client side validation rather than just letting the browser handle it.  In that case the JS library may be assigning the first option by default when run in a browser that supports JS.  If you're running your tests using the rack-test driver that won't happen (no JS support), so nothing is selected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've changed the logic of my test.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. [How to install lxml on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504810/how-to-install-lxml-on-ubuntu#6504860) helped me by

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```