# Install Python module easygui on Ubuntu 16.04 without Pip or setup.py

Tags: python, ubuntu, module, installation, easygui

I am new to Ubuntu coming from Windows.  I need to install the easygui Python module but the version currently on PyPI has issues.  The previous release 0.97 is fine.  Using `pip install easygui` installs 0.98.  I can download the 0.97 library from SourceForge and I want to install it on Ubuntu 16.04.  The download does not have a setup.py file (which I get how to use to install libraries).  In Windows I could copy the easygui.py file to the Libs directory and call the module.  Where do I put this file in Linux 16.04?  The file structure is confusing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pip to specify the version of the module you would like to install:

```
pip install easygui==0.97
```

You could also tack on the flag `--force-reinstall` if you run into trouble with the module being installed already.

---

as a side note: This might be a good time to start using virtual environments.

Comment: Thanks @RagingRoosevelt.  I had my Bash syntax wrong.  I did try sudo install easygui-0.97.

Answer (score 2):

If you have easy_install working, you could try:

"`sudo easy_install easygui`"

or if you want to specify the location or if you do not have the root privileges:

"`easy_install --install-dir=here-some-folder-where-to-install easygui`"

If you want to install some specific version of the tool with the easygui, perhaps this post helps:

[Install particular version with easy_install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833011/install-particular-version-with-easy-install)

At least "`sudo easy_install easygui==0.97`" worked for me.